# Solr Core Auto Discovery

Tags: solr

I'm working on a new Solr install of 4.10.2. Someone else set up a working version, but he has no idea how he did it. I need to be sure I know how to reproduce it so I'm faced with a state where I have an existing, operating core in the existing `solr.home`. I need to build out a fresh install, insert this core directory and have it be operational. Here's what I have based on his existing work:

1. A default install of Solr 4.10.2 installed in `/opt/solr`. This is basically just the `example/` directory extracted from the downloaded tarball.
2. An upstart script whose relevant bits look like this:

   ```
   chdir /opt/solr
   exec java -Djetty.port=8984 -Dsolr.solr.home=solr -jar start.jar
   ```
3. The working (i.e. fully populated) core directory in place at `/opt/solr/solr/my-core`. The default `collection1` directory also exists here.

The `solr.xml` file, also in `/opt/solr/solr` is also from his working instance and looks like this:

```
<solr>

  <solrcloud>
    <str name="host">${host:}</str>
    <int name="hostPort">${jetty.port:8984}</int>
    <str name="hostContext">${hostContext:solr}</str>
    <int name="zkClientTimeout">${zkClientTimeout:30000}</int>
    <bool name="genericCoreNodeNames">${genericCoreNodeNames:true}</bool>
  </solrcloud>

  <shardHandlerFactory name="shardHandlerFactory"
    class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
    <int name="socketTimeout">${socketTimeout:0}</int>
    <int name="connTimeout">${connTimeout:0}</int>
  </shardHandlerFactory>

</solr>
```

When I hit the Solr Admin URL on port 8984, the **Core Selector** dropdown includes `collection1`, but not  `my-core`. Simiarly, the **Core Admin** section only lists `collection1`.

What am I missing here that's preventing my core (`my-core`) from being recognized?

Just digging into Solr 4 and would like to use the new syntax so I'm ready for future versions.

**UPDATE 1/30**

Reading through `/var/log/upstart/solr.log` after starting the service, I don't see any errors. In fact, the core seems to be detected just fine. It just doesn't show up in the UI.

```
3688 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema  ? Reading Solr Schema from /opt/solr-4.10.2/solr/my-core/conf/schema.xml
3857 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema  ? [My Core] Schema name=drupal-4.2-solr-4.x
```

Comment: I have similar problem - did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, in which one collection I created showed up in the Core Selector dropdown but one I created just before that was missing.  But I noticed a shard showed up for the absent one in the Cloud-->Graph display.  I clicked on the IP address for that shard.  When I then went back to the Core Selector dropdown I saw that that collection was now being displayed.

Worth a try...